# What is the most passive way to create a timer loop?

Tags: java, loops, time

For those of you need to know, I'm writing a plugin for CraftBukkit, which is a modded version of Minecraft, and I'm a beginner level java programmer. I have what I think is a really basic question.

I'm trying to implement a countdown that executes methods to send messages to players every second for 20 seconds.

Obviously, I can't simply create a loop that loops for 20 seconds, because that loop will freeze the main thread until it finishes, which is unacceptable. (There is a lot of game code executing)

What are some approaches to creating a loop that will run passively or without halting the main thread?

The only thing I can possibly think is creating a new thread to run the countdown in.
Surely there is a simpler way to do this?

So you aren't confused, the countdown isn't initialized as part of some main loop, its initialized linearly by a user command listener, but its code executes in the main loop. What I mean by that is I need to actually START a loop that checks time, because this code is only executed once.

Sorry if I'm not being clear or making sense.

Comment: Are you working with `Swing`?

Comment: Nope, not using Swing. the util Timer suited my needs better Thanks!

Comment: Then you should use a very reliable API in `java.util.concurrent` package which is `ScheduledExecutorService`. Have a look at this example : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16445807/1981279

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) if you are not using Swing for GUI/Graphics (not familiar with CraftBukkit, so that will be up to you to determine). In particular, look at forms of `schedule` which allow a task to be repeated at fixed intervals.

`javax.swing.Timer` is similar. The biggest difference (aside from the interfaces used to respond to timers being triggered) is that `javax.swing.Timer` utilizes the EDT (event dispatch thread) to run events. If you're using a Swing GUI, this thread is already present and running and you want to use it. If you're not using Swing or AWT, then this is extra overhead that you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` and conveniently schedule a countdown task at 1-second intervals.

Alternatively, if you task must run on the Event Dispatch Thread (the "GUI thread"), you'll be better served by `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: I think javax.swing.Timer is exactly what i'm looking for. I'm reading the docs but it basically adds the code to be executed to a delay that allows the main thread to continue running while the delay runs out correct?

Comment: @cody Yes, that's what all the task schedulers do. Swing Timer is specific in that it executes the task on the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html):

```java
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //...Perform a task...
    }
};
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Comment: I am strongly inclined to think that `javax.swing` classes should only be used if you're actually building a Swing GUI (which is almost certainly not the case here).