# Get content from screen after every T minutes on android phone

Tags: android, selenium, appium

What is the best way to get text of all EditTexts available on a screen in an android phone after every 5 minutes or say T minutes.
Is there any way say using selenium or say Appium or any other such framework, that we can scrape content of current screen on android phone.

I am making and android app to try out the same. How this can be done. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Can try [running a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447464/1746118) in a parallel thread with following details from Appium :

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
// Note that timer has been declared final, to allow use in anon. class below
timer.schedule( new TimerTask()
{
    private int i = 10;
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("5 Mins Later");
        List<WebElement> editTexts= driver.findElements(By.XPath("//android.widget.EditText");
        for(int j=0;j<editTexts.size();j++){
           System.out.println("Element " + j+1 + " text : " + editTexts.get(j).getText()); //perform what action you want or get the details from
        }
        if (--i < 1) timer.cancel(); // Count down ten times, then cancel
    }
}, 30000*10, 30000*10 //Note the second argument for repetition (time in milli-seconds
);
```